# LendingClub.com API 500 Error for Buying Notes on Secondary Market

Tags: php, json, rest, lending-club-api

I have been able to make API requests with other endpoints just fine, but the endpoint for making buys does not seem to work at all. It seems like it is a server error on their end, but I figured I would ask on here just in case I am making a careless mistake.

I have written multiple versions of my function but this is one:

```
function getLCInfo($endpoint, $getData = false) {
  $api_url = "https://api.lendingclub.com/api/investor/";
  $verison = "v1";
  $account_id = "12345678";
  $ContentType = "application/json";

  $url = "$api_url$verison/accounts/$account_id/$endpoint/";

  if($getData) {
    $url .= "?" . urldecode(http_build_query($getData));

    echo $url;
  }


  $key = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa99999999";

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
              array('Authorization: ' . $key, 
                    'Content-type: ' . $ContentType , 
                    'Accept: ' . $ContentType, 
                    'X-LC-Application-Key: ' . $account_id));

  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  $output = curl_exec( $ch );

  curl_close( $ch );

  return json_decode($output);
}
```

This is their [documentation](https://www.lendingclub.com/foliofn/APIDocumentationBuy.action):

> This subresource provides a summary of the investor's account.
>
> Operation: GET
>
> URL: https://api.lendingclub.com/api/investor/v1/accounts/[investor
>   id]/trades/
>
> URL Parameters: Investor Id - This can be obtained from the Account
>   Summary section on Lending Club website when a user is logged in.
>
> Query Parameters: None.
>
> Supported Formats: JSON request for buy notes
>
> Request/ Response Headers: NAME   TYPE    NULLABLE    DESCRIPTION
>   Aid   String  No  The ID of the investor upon whose behalf the partner is
>   requesting to buy one or more notes for notes Array   No  An array of one
>   or more notes loanId  String  No  Numeric identifier of the loan whose
>   note requested for purchase orderId   String  No  Numeric identifier of
>   the order for the note noteId String  No  Numeric identifier of the note
>   bidPrice  String  No  Positive numeric value in dollars ($) and cents
>   representing the buy price desired for the note Sample request: JSON —
>
> ```
> {     "aid":70654,"notes":    [       {"loanId":3349795,"orderId":19979983,"noteId":5730626,"bidPrice":9.79},
>   {"loanId":707414,"orderId":1369944,"noteId":4154191,"bidPrice":23.84},
>   {"loanId":1076461,"orderId":2133757,"noteId":7827843,"bidPrice":34.45}
> ```
>
> ]
>       }
>
> Sample Response—
>
> ```
> {     buyNoteConfirmations:       [ 3 ] :         {           loanId:  3349795            noteId:  5730626            bidPrice:  9.79 
>       outstandingAccruedInterest:  null           outstandingPrincipal:  null 
>       yieldToMaturity:  null              executionStatus:            [ 1 ] :   "
> ```
>
> NOTE_DOES_NOT_EXIST "         } 
>         1: {            loanId:  707414             noteId:  4154191            bidPrice:  23.84            outstandingAccruedInterest:  null           outstandingPrincipal:  null 
>             yieldToMaturity:  null              executionStatus:            [ 1 ] :   "
>   NOTE_NOT_AVAILABLE " 
>             } 
>         2: {            loanId:  1076461            noteId:  7827843            bidPrice:  34.45            outstandingAccruedInterest:  null           outstandingPrincipal:  null             yieldToMaturity:  null              executionStatus:            [ 1 ] 0:   "
>   SUCCESS_PENDING_SETTLEMENT " 
>         }     }

This is what happens when I test in Postman 
POSTing data:

```
POST /api/investor/v1/accounts/87308218/trades/ HTTP/1.1
Host: api.lendingclub.com
Authorization: aaaaaaaaaaa111111
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 68d283a6-08f0-6789-3542-3a1baa554ce7

{
    "aid":70654,"notes":
    [
        {"loanId":3349795,"orderId":19979983,"noteId":5730626,"bidPrice":9.79}, 
        {"loanId":707414,"orderId":1369944,"noteId":4154191,"bidPrice":23.84}, 
        {"loanId":1076461,"orderId":2133757,"noteId":7827843,"bidPrice":34.45}
    ]
}
```

and I tried to use GET like their documentation says.

```
GET /api/investor/v1/accounts/87308218/trades/?aid=12345678&amp;notes[0][loanId]=17213188&amp;notes[0][orderId]=25300948&amp;notes[0][noteId]=48382917&amp;notes[0][bidPrice]=6.77&amp;notes[1][loanId]=17213188&amp;notes[1][orderId]=25300943&amp;notes[1][noteId]=48382538&amp;notes[1][bidPrice]=6.77 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.lendingclub.com
Authorization: aaaaaaaaaaa111111
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: b34cb60b-91ea-c82e-349f-d395b01b1dc0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Turns out LendingClub had incorrect info on their documentation (super frustrating!).

My solution was to change the Operation to POST instead of GET and the endpoint was incorrect.

They have URL: https://api.lendingclub.com/api/investor/v1/accounts/[investor id]/trades/, it should be URL: https://api.lendingclub.com/api/investor/v1/accounts//trades/buy
(which actually makes much more sense since their API's sell endpoint ends with /trades/sell.

I hope some developer at LendingClub reads this and edits the API documentation, I'm sure I'm not alone with this!